# GAE Datastore Many To Many Relationship Query

Tags: google-app-engine, many-to-many, google-cloud-datastore

The Story:

Say you are creating a site where people can search for each other based on their favorite movies. So you have `User` and `Movie` as your main two entities.  There are few options when it comes to relating `Users` and `Movies` to capture the notion of a favorite movie.

First: Create a list of `Movie` keys on `User`

The models may then look something like this

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()
    favorite_movies = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Movie, repeated=True)

class Movie(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.TextProperty()
```

Second: Create a separate entity for the relationship

The the models may then look like the following

```
class User(ndb.Model):
    username = ndb.StringProperty()
    userid = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    email = ndb.StringProperty()

class Movie(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty()
    description = ndb.TextProperty()

class FavoriteMovie(ndb.Model):
    user = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)
    movie = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Movie)
    rating = ndb.IntegerProperty()
```

One of the benefits of taking the second approach is that we can add additional information about the relationship such as the rating a user gave to his/her favorite movie.  Another reason to consider the second approach is if both sides have lots of relationships. In this example a user has lots of favorite movies and a movie is favorited by lots of users.

Now say we don't know if people will have lots of favorite movies or if movies will be favorited by lots of people and we would like to be flexible so that we don't need to make a rushed design change. Additionally you may want to let users rate their favorite movies at some point and again would like some flexibility there. However, one thing that we do know is that if this site gets big, efficiency is king and ultimately if flexibility means reduced efficiency we would rather not lose the efficiency. The second approach is a cause for concern then because the docs warn us that it will require additional calls to the database to traverse the relationships.

So to know if efficiency will be a problem we need to look at the kinds of queries we will need to run and in our case the most commonly executed query will be something like "Give me all of the users who have Forest Gump as a favorite movie" or "Give me all of the users that have Forest Gump and Cast Away as a favorite movie". We also need to know what data we need when. Most likely we wont need the entire user to come back for those queries and instead will only need a name, and a photo back to build our list of users on the UI. Given this, we can denormalize our data a bit and put the user's name and photo url on the relationship. Doing this would allow us to avoid making subsequent calls to the database for that data and if the person actually picks a user to view his/her profile we can make the call to the database then.

The Question:

These have been thoughts on a problem similar to the one described above.  As you may be able to tell I'm leaning towards using the second approach to model my many-to-many relationship.  There is one major concern I have however. In the second query example I gave I asked for users with Forest Gump **AND** Cast Away as favorites. I don't know how this would be done efficiently with the second approach and it is crucial that users be able to ask that sort of question.  Also, what effect would asking for users with Forest Gump **OR** Cast Away as favorites have. Are these concerns enough to use the first approach or is there an even better approach that I have not considered here?

I appreciate any thoughts on the subject.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: Which way did you end up going and how did it work out?